# How to Set Up a Stun Server with Node.js

Tags: audio, webrtc, stun

I am currently using a Stun server (A public one). However, I need to have good audio quality and am slightly confused by Stun servers.

1. Does a Stun server affect sound quality? I researched Stun servers and it seems like they are only for identifying IP addresses (?) (or something like that), so I am slightly confused as another Google search result told me that, to get the best audio quality for streaming, you need to make your own Stun server.
2. Is using a public Stun server OK? I need a server that can take lots of usage and high quality audio (as I said above, not sure if Stun server affects audio/quality), and will be used for streaming music and other high quality audio.

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A STUN server has nothing to do with the audio quality. It's only used to find your IP address. Something that could affect latency/network quality is a TURN server as it is a relay server where data passes through. TURN is used when a direct connection between the peers isn't possible using the STUN method.

To have better quality you need to set the media parameters when you ask them from `getUserMedia`. Here are the constraints you can use for audio https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints.